# How to encrypt information in ActiveAdmin comments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, comments, activeadmin

this is a general can I do this and if so, how, type question.  ActiveAdmin has a nifty built in `ActiveAdmin::Comments` class which enables a "comments" section to be dropped into an ActiveAdmin page.  AA handles the creation of the `active_admin_comments` table in the database and it just works, with the content of the comment in the `body` attribute.  There is also a `resource_type` attribute which specifies which model the comments are associated with.

We want to add this field to one of our pages, but due to SOX compliance the values entered have to be encrypted.  Rails 7, which I'm using, has support for encryption at the model layer right out of the box and I'd very much like to leverage that for these comments.  I've tried monkey patching encryption in like so:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class Comments < ApplicationRecord
    encrypts :body
  end
end
```

in a model file but it doesn't seem to be working, querying the database doesn't show the input as encrypted.  Is there an easy way to add encryption, preferably limited to specific resource types, to ActiveAdmin comments?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to an installed ActiveAdmin instance to test this solution but I can see right away that you have the wrong class name and you're inheriting from the wrong class name:

```rb
class Comments < ApplicationRecord
```

Make sure you look at [the original class definition](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/51689e48ec3faa51127b8462b2219e5e0c09ad8a/lib/active_admin/orm/active_record/comments/comment.rb#L3):

```rb
module ActiveAdmin
  class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    # ...
  end
end
```

Model names are singular and you must inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`, not your app's own customized `ApplicationRecord` class.

This isn't guaranteed to work for a couple of reasons:

1. [ActiveAdmin is complex](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/51689e48ec3faa51127b8462b2219e5e0c09ad8a/lib/active_admin/orm/active_record/comments.rb) and monkey-patching it might prove difficult
2. [`ActiveRecord::Encryption` supports both encrypted and unencrypted data in a single column](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_encryption.html#support-for-unencrypted-data) but you must configure your application to support it first